# create a zoom pad effect with ffmpeg but instead of black background put a image background?

Tags: ffmpeg, zooming, effect

i need to create a zoom effect with frame image background  instead of black background

how is possible this

please help me

this is my command

```
ffmpeg -i duke2.jpg    -filter_complex      "pad=  w=560:h=200:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2',zoompan=  z='zoom+0.002':d=25*4:s=1280x800"    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 zzout.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is,

```
ffmpeg -i duke2.jpg -i bg.jpg -filter_complex
     "[0]pad= w=560:h=200:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2':color=black@0,format=yuva444p,
         zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':d=25*4:s=1280x800[fg];[1][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"
       -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 zzout.mp4
```

Comment: hi very sorry but i need that the background image is static and use another background image not the same image .

Comment: hi please you can put two random images , i dont know the dimensions of images , i see my output with black background